# powershell - Script to add workers hours

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have not found a way to make this happen or a site that has something close. I may just not know how to ask this about this operation, so I will try here.

What I have is a CSV with a list of employees hours worked each day (regular and OT) all in separate rows. The columns have headers. Employee name, Date, Regular Hours, and OT Hours are in separate columns. 
The challenge is that for employee Bob, there may be 20 rows for one day. Bob applies a slice of time to different projects all day. Then of course there are multiple days and multiple employees. 
What I am trying to end up with is a report that shows all of the regular and OT hours (separately) for each employee on a daily basis.

I started with this, which parses the SV and gives me just the columns of interest. However, this outputs just a long list of every row that matches and that is not going to get me where I need to go.

```
$employees = import-csv "c:\Test1.csv"
ForEach ($employee in $employees){
$employeeName = $($employee.'Resource name')
$WorkDate = $($employee.'Charge Date')
$RegHours = $($employee.RegHours)
$OT = $($employee.OTHours)
Write-host $employeeName $WorkDate $RegHours
}
```

I then attempted to format the output in an attempt to start consolidating the output. Because it seems to me that I will need 2 consolidations. One to get all of the users data together, separate from the other users, and one to get all of the same date under each user together. Then, a SUM can be performed on each day, for each user. At least that is how I am viewing it at this point.

So this is the formatting attempt. But this just give headers to each row. It does not consolidate. The headers are nice, but the user data needs to be consolidated under the header for it to be useful.

```
 $employees = import-csv "C:\test2.csv"
ForEach ($employee in $employees)
{
$employeeName = $($employee.'Resource name')
$WorkDate = $($employee.'Charge Date')
$RegHours = $($employee.RegHours)
$OT = $($employee.OTHours)

$obj = $null
 $obj = New-Object System.Object
 $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Employee Name" -Value $employeeName
 $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Work Date" -Value $WorkDate
 $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Regular Hours" -Value $RegHours

$obj | Format-table 
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you have so far to make this a valid question.

Comment: show a representative data file as well as what code you have tried

Comment: This was resolved using a Pivot Table in Excel.